# Finding Daily Returns in R for multiple worksheets in the same workbook and merge them?

Tags: r, excel, merge, time-series

Hi i currently have 70 sheets under the same excel workbook and i am trying to find daily returns based on the data and then merge all 70 sheets into one data frame. All of the 70 sheets contain Date and Open price. Here is my code so far for the software R

```
require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook(system.file("crypto.xlsx", package = "XLConnect"))
crypto = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb),startRow=1,endRow = 20, endCol=2)
```

I want to find returns of each sheet and then merge all 70 into one data frame. However the time period is different in all of these sheets and i cant find a way to merge them. In the Final dataframe i want the variables `Date, Price1, Dailyreturn1, Price2, DailyReturn2 ......... Price70, DailyReturn70` Any help would be appreciated with returns and merge.

Here is how my data looks like with a lot more rows and the data format is the same for all 70 sheets.

```
Date        Open        High    Low    Close   Market Cap
28-Apr-13   135.3       135.98  132.1  134.21  1,500,520,000
29-Apr-13   134.44      147.49  134    144.54  1,491,160,000
30-Apr-13   144         146.93  134.05 139     1,597,780,000
1-May-13    139         139.89  107.72 116.99  1,542,820,000
```

and i want the end result to look somewhat like this with all 70 sheets combined into one. DR is for Daily return

```
Date Open1 DR1 Open2 DR2 Open3 DR3............Open70 DR70
```

Comment: What is *Price* or *DailyReturn*? Please try your output on one sheet.

Comment: Daily return is just a simple return based on the open price.

Comment: You have two desired results. And again did you make any attempt after `crypto ...`?

Comment: i tried using the merge function to merge different dataframes for example merge(crypto[1],crypto[2]) but i am having issues because all of these 70 sheets have different time ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the chain merge with `Reduce` keeping all x rows (i.e., left join). But first update list to rename columns which can be done in a `lapply` with `setNames`.

```
# ASSUME ALL DFs ARE ONLY Date and Open
crypto2 <- lapply(seq_along(crypto), function(i)
  setNames(crypto[[i]], c("Date", paste0("DR", i))))

finaldf <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Date", all.x=TRUE), crypto2)
```

NOTE: Be very careful with this `Reduce` approach if your data has duplicate dates with different *Open* values as the `merge` will grow large quickly since each join combination will be returned.

**Example** with random data *(aggregate used to return only unique dates per above warning)*

```
set.seed(123)

crypto <- lapply(seq(10), function(i)
  aggregate(Open~Date, data.frame(
    Date = Sys.Date()- sapply(seq(30), function(i) sample(15,1,replace=TRUE)),
    Open = abs(rnorm(30)*100)
  ), FUN=max))

crypto2 <- lapply(seq_along(crypto), function(i)
  setNames(crypto[[i]], c("Date", paste0("DR", i))))

finaldf <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Date", all.x=TRUE), crypto2)
```

**Output**

```
finaldf
#          Date       DR1       DR2       DR3        DR4       DR5       DR6       DR7       DR8       DR9      DR10
# 1  2017-11-12  70.92008  56.29895  37.56029 136.403745 100.56363        NA 138.80490  28.73408  64.75134 195.07210
# 2  2017-11-13 102.55714 212.84519 190.23618 199.274849 127.22668        NA 151.60676        NA 188.63252  90.35164
# 3  2017-11-15  44.82098 105.27115 135.98407 101.755864 123.56935 123.66758 107.49451        NA  91.35660  45.73573
# 4  2017-11-16  22.04866  36.89645  63.07541 151.921771  43.88187 103.96804 168.75895 144.14618  90.44355        NA
# 5  2017-11-17 122.07177  37.45809 229.30790 175.323736  88.33028  35.88557  84.90611  72.82191  23.11149  70.10036
# 6  2017-11-18 109.68390        NA 159.85088  62.418747 163.35684 116.52534 154.66092  90.42150  33.33700  79.76007
# 7  2017-11-19 205.00847        NA  78.86220 246.589819        NA  60.85572        NA 245.80605  85.52022 184.32663
# 8  2017-11-20 114.88076  37.24388 154.75811  72.160444  71.27033  60.53707 107.40123  11.88494 131.82207  76.46060
# 9  2017-11-21  33.32074 126.01552  50.21987 257.145815 222.49877  50.63335 208.67174 106.10953 115.29362 148.37795
# 10 2017-11-22 230.91689  21.53805  11.36399  97.400958 239.74525  96.72673        NA  58.99827 216.14158 122.09637
# 11 2017-11-24  33.17820 104.91770  66.47694         NA  45.03386 142.05655 260.16997 154.04424        NA 103.81310
# 12 2017-11-25  37.96395  97.69734  52.11173  57.185006 163.63793  18.43089 141.52819 154.77765  65.80102 109.95509
# 13 2017-11-26  37.06600  76.90422 175.65274   3.303616 177.95029 194.58512  87.52555 118.71868  39.43948 111.64164
```

Comment: Yes it did work now i have all the open prices for all currencies in one data frame as shown in the example you provided. I have one more step to go which i am having trouble with. I want to apply a formula to all the DR1 to DR70 for daily return. For example the formula i want to apply based on the example data will look like (102.55714-70.92008)/70.92008 but it will cover all the data from DR1 to DR70. Any help would be appreciated on this